# SQL Server: DELETE FROM OPENDATASOURCE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE( 
       'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
       'Data Source=d:\JobFiles\MyFile.xlsx; 
        Extended properties=Excel 8.0')...MySheet$
```

So does this:

```
INSERT INTO OPENDATASOURCE( 
       'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
       'Data Source=d:\JobFiles\MyFile.xlsx; 
        Extended properties=Excel 8.0')...MySheet$
SELECT * FROM blahblahblah
```

So why not?

```
DELETE FROM OPENDATASOURCE( 
        'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
        'Data Source=d:\JobFiles\MyFile.xlsx;
         Extended properties=Excel 8.0')...MySheet$
```

I've done some searching with no real luck. At the end of the day, all I need is the excel rows deleted before I can insert fresh data and I want to achieve this with SQL only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delete entire rows via OPENDATASOURCE. According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819:

> **Delete**
>
> You are more restricted in deleting Excel data than data from a
>   relational data source. In a relational database, "row" has no meaning
>   or existence apart from "record"; in an Excel worksheet, this is not
>   true. You can delete values in fields (cells). However, you cannot:
>
> - Delete an entire record at once or you receive the following error message:
>
> *Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM.*
>
> You can only delete a record by blanking out the contents of each
>   individual field.
>
> - Delete the value in a cell containing an Excel formula or you receive the following error message:
>
> *Operation is not allowed in this context.*
>
> - You cannot delete the empty spreadsheet row(s) in which the deleted data was located, and your recordset will continue to display empty
>     records corresponding to these empty rows.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Yuriry - that's what I thought.

For anyone else in my situation, this was my 'cleanest' workaround: get a blank version of the file (in my case, 'MyFileBlank.xlsx') and follow the below:

```
--delete existing file
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'del d:\JobFiles\MyFile.xlsx' 
go

--create new file from blank template
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'copy d:\JobFiles\MyFileBlank.xlsx d:\JobFiles\MyFile.xlsx' 
go

INSERT INTO OPENDATASOURCE( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Data Source=d:\JobFiles\MyFile.xlsx; 
        Extended properties=Excel 8.0')...MySheet$
SELECT * FROM blahblahblah
```