# SQL Server - Clear and Populate Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, openrowset

I need to push data from SQL Server 2014 into Excel sheets. As the sheets will not change, I need to clear the sheets first.

My queries are at the bottom.

**NOTE** - due to the nature of this, I cannot simply pull the data into Excel.

The UPDATE appears to lock-up the Excel file. I can run the insert multiple times without issue, but the UPDATE prevents further operations from actually changing the file.

1. Run UPDATE: Successful, sheet is cleared
2. Run INSERT: **fail** The SQL executes without error, but the file is not populated

Code:

```
UPDATE OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                   'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Workspace\WorkBook01.xlsx',
                   'SELECT col_01, col_01 FROM [Sheet1$]')
SET col_01 = NULL,
    col_02 = NULL
WHERE col_01 IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                        'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Workspace\WorkBook01.xlsx',
                        'SELECT col_01, col_02 FROM [Sheet1$]')
    SELECT col_01, col_01 
    FROM [dbo].[table_data];
```

**EDIT - Additonal Details**
The code is used due to the nature of the task that needs to be done (the file structure was not defined by me, but I need to work with it). The requirements are outlined below:

1. There are over 30 .xlsx files, all of which have 3 or more sheets
2. Rows across the sheets reference a "master data" sheet stored in each file (not an external reference)
3. The master data sheet must have the values directly inserted (e.g. not referencing an external source)

I need to update the "master data" sheets across all files (without using an external reference). The code above is used because I can quickly script-out the SQL to do this operation for all files.

**NOTE** - I am aware this would be MUCH easier if the "master sheets" simply pulled the data from the database, or if they all referenced one external file... this wasn't my call, but I do need to maintain the sheets.

Comment: Can you use SSIS?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018502/how-to-overwrite-excel-destination-in-ssis

Comment: Does your insert work as expected if you don't run the update first? If so, you could create a blank template file, and just copy your template file over the existing file before running your insert script.

Comment: How many rows are you inserting?

Comment: Yes, the `insert` is working fine, and can be run multiple times in a row without issue. The `update` works, and the `insert` says it worked successfully afterwards, but the sheet is blank (except for the headers)

Comment: You never answered @TabAlleman 's question regarding SSIS. I'd use SSIS if possible, if not, consider the blank template file approach. Also, under what conditions does the file lock seem to be lifted? If you delay between running the update and insert does it work?

Comment: Thanks, I don't think SSIS is an option with the setup, but will look into it. Otherwise I'll see about the template.

Comment: The insert doesn't work work after a delay. I discovered the issue is setting the Excel values to NULL (empty string also sets to NULL). This breaks something, and you cannot delete rows using `OPENROWSET` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849296/sql-server-delete-from-opendatasource

Answer (score 2):

The answer is two fold. The bottom line is it cannot be done as far as I can tell.

1. Rows cannot be delete via `OPENROWSET`
2. Setting a row's values to `NULL` (empty string defaults to `NULL`) causes an issue with the next insert where the data is not inserted (no warning raised in SQL).

This is further covered in here: [SQL Server: DELETE FROM OPENDATASOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849296/sql-server-delete-from-opendatasource)

**NOTE** - The accepted answer in the link says that rows can be "blanked out"; however, in my experience this causes an error with the next `INSERT`.

Use `SELECT FROM OPENROWSET(...)` before the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` to more accurately see the values assigned than visible in Excel (Excel shows NULL as empty lines).

Comment: Work around - there is an (ugly) work around for this issue. **1)** Add an 'Order ID' to the Excel and results with `ROW NUMBER` **2)** dump table results into temp table with 'Order ID' row generated with `ROW_NUMBER` **3)** `LEFT JOIN` from `OPENROWSET` onto table based on 'Order ID' **4)** use `IsNull` to default missing values to '0' or 'x' **5)** Check row counts, if the DB table has more rows, insert them using `WHERE order_id > @excl_count` **6)** enclose in a cursor for all Excel files to bulk update the results in all files quickly

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fathom why you would adopt such a complicated approach.  All you need to do is to export your data in CSV format and then simply read it into excel using File->Open.  One caveat: Excel will expect an initial row that specifies the column names--again, quoted and comma-separated: if this is absent, Excel will simply, silently DISCARD the first row of your data.

So, all you really need to do is:

**SPOOL 'wherever.xls'

SELECT DISTINCT( "\"col1name\",\"col2name\",\"col3name" ) FROM < anyTableWillDo>;

SELECT "\"", col1name, "\",\"", col2name, "\",\"", col3name, "\""
FROM    < yourSubjectTable>;

SPOOL OFF;**

Comment: Thank you for this, I have added details to my original post concerning why I am using the approach. It is to be able to bulk update many files without using an external reference/source.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I should put this in comment instead of answer but I don't have enough points.   I don't think anything is wrong with your logic,    it looks like the updating to NULL is doing something weird with the contents.      I opened with excel, then cleared the cells.    The insert worked perfect.

I used a select to look at the cell contents after the update to NULL,  and the cells showed up with NULL.      Then I couldn't get the insert to work after that.

```
select * from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                        'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\junk\test.xlsx;',
                        'SELECT *  FROM [Sheet1$]')
```